# Wake me at 6 AM, respecting daylight savings and time-zone. Possible?

Tags: integrated-circuit, pulse

I'm an electronics noob.

I want to be woken up at 6 AM every morning (irrespective of daylight savings, irrespective of time-zone) by a device which has no visual display, no wires, and works forever.

How close is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this needs two parts:

1. A part that knows what "6am" means where you are in terms of counting ticks of some clock
2. A part that is good at generating ticks

The first part needs to know which time zone you're in. Since you define that your device mustn't have a user interface, that means your device must be able to determine its position to a degree sufficient for time zone determination.

Time zones are really ... effed up. So, either GPS or cellular phone service it is to locate itself.

Now, you sounded like you wanted this device to work for a long time, but mobile carrier company politics and cellular standards change, so GPS is probably the better choice to know your location.

Then, this first device also requires knowledge and understanding of time zones. Time zone data is actually relatively complex, so you'd probably be best of with something that runs a proper operating system, think of a smartphone processor or whatever powers your car's entertainment system. Feed the current time zone data, and pray politics doesn't change that! But you'd be out of luck – I recommend researching `TZDATA` and how often that changes because someone, somewhere, decided that the region they rule belongs to a different time zone, or changes when the DST switch happens, or whether there's a leap second or…

So, to be realistic, you'd need some kind of internet connection to download new time zone data. Darn! There goes our plan to just rely on GPS.

But now we've got something

- with a proper processor running a proper OS
- with internet connectivity
- with GPS (for reasons given below)
- without user interface

I don't know, but that sounds like "smartphone in a box" to me!

Why GPS:

We haven't talked about where the clock ticks come from, about the second device. Now, getting good oscillations is a problem as old as electronics, especially digital ones, and there's different solutions to it. Cheap wristwatches, USB gadgets or your average MP3 player use crystals, typically in accuracy regions of 10 to 25 ppm (parts per million). A year has about 31 million seconds, so a clock based on that might tick some 5 to 13 seconds wrong *per year*.

You can get that much lower by buying more expensive crystals and putting them in small temperature-controlled ovens – about 100 ppb are possible with that, so a factor of 50 better than your pure crystal, but over a clock lifetime of 50 years, still quite a few seconds.

Then, there's atomic clocks with single- and low two-digit ppb accuracies. Yeah. That's an expensive alarm clock that you're building there!

Well, luckily, you can use someone else's atomic clock (network): GPS is in fact a global clock-coordination system. The fact that you get location info is kind of a welcome side effect (at least to me as communications engineer, who very much relies on good clocks ;) ).

So, buy a GPS-disciplined clock. These are nearly as accurate as the atomic clocks controlling the GPS satellites, and only cost a couple hundred dollars.

About the no-wire part: everything needs power, so you better have some wireless charging coil in there, and an external wireless charger.

Comment: could be solar powered - especially if it only runs the internet once a week and the GPS once per hour. (this is making the assumption that the user won't cross a time locale border while asleep, or do so and then desire to sleep for less than 1h... (something that could happen in a vehicle)

Comment: Nice try, +1.  However, the OP says he want 6:00 AM *irrespective* of the time zone or daylight savings time.  So all you need is to find GMT, which doesn't require knowing where you are.  A GPS-disciplined clock still makes sense, but only needs to check in with the GPS system very occasionally to correct for whatever frequency error the local crystal has.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Ah! I meant _respecting_ time zones and DLS. Title corrected.